# Display shortcode instead of out of stock message in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

When a variable is out of stock, I would prefer to display a form through a shortcode, instead of the original text message.

You can see the original out of stock message here (select size 48) http://teste.marianoshoes.com/product/artigo/

I know how to add the plugin files and change them through my child theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter hook excatly for this task. Add this to your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'my_woocommerce_get_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function my_woocommerce_get_availability_text( $availability, $product) {
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        if (function_exists('iphorm_popup')) {
            $availability = iphorm_popup(4, 'Change this to the text or HTML that will trigger the popup');   
        } else {
            $availability = 'Your out of stock text here';
        }
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I display this text+shortcode form there? <?php if (function_exists('iphorm_popup')) echo iphorm_popup(4, 'Change this to the text or HTML that will trigger the popup'); ?>

Comment: does show an error in dreamweaver when I paste it in the functions file. I added a comma after 'my_woocommerce_get_availability_text' (first line), but when when I uploaded online,the site went blank.

Comment: Argl sorry. There was heavy errors in my code. Now it should work.